# sitecore package 6.2 quick look at content

Tags: deployment, package, sitecore

I know that you can create an xml file detailing the contents when you create a package, but is there an easy way to determine what is in a package when it is just a zip file sitting on a file server or something?

This is in version 6.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Open the Package Designer on the server where the zip is. In the New menu click the dropdown and select "From Existing." From here pick the package and it will open in the designer.

Here's a blog post visually showing you the idea: [Inspecting Sitecore Packages Before You Install Them](http://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2011/03/14/inspecting-packages.aspx)

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking for and it makes sense that this is where to look for it in retrospect.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a package with any archive editor (for instance, [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)). The main ZIP contains another ZIP, called package.zip. The package.zip in its turn contains a number of folder. The most interesting to you are probably:

- files
- items
- security

The contents of /files folder corresponds to the file system structure under the website root.  For instance:

- /App_Config/Include/my.config
- /bin/my.dll
- /xsl/my.xsl

The contents of the /items folder is a directory structure. The path to an XML representation of each item starts with the folder named like the database holding the item, then down the path of the item in the content tree (starting from /sitecore), then the ID of the item, next the language, and finally the version. For instance:

- \items\core\sitecore\layout\Layouts\my layout{GUID-GOES-HERE}\en\1\xml

"xml" is the name of the XML file containing the item data.

The contents of /security folder is simpler:

- \security\roles\sitecore\My Power Users

There are other folders inside the package.zip, but those primarily hold the metadata of the package, like readme, license, etc.

I suppose it's a superfluous warning, but still: don't try to edit anything there. It makes sense for a quick look only to make sure something is or is not in the package.
Hope this helps.